# Do we need to add webdriver paths into the pom file each time we create a new class

Tags: selenium

I have created a new class and added this piece there but I get an error. The same piece runs on another class.

```
package BeginnerPrograms;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;


public class WebLocators {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   
        driver.get("http://www.developer.salesforce.com/signup");

    }

}
```

Error received: `The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;`

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't need to add `WebDriver` path into the **POM** file.

Just declare that in `@BeforeSuite` if you are using **TestNG** or in your `TestBase` class.

and use the instance of driver everywhere.

**TestNG Example :**

```
@BeforeSuite
public void setUpSuite() { 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe")
}
```

**Only Java Example :**

```
public class TestBase{
  
    public TestBase(){
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe")
       //Your other constructor stuff here.  
      }
  }
```

and in your `TestClass`, use it like this :

```
public class TestClass extends TestBase{

public void someTestMethod(){
   new TestBase();
//proceed with your test case here
}
}
```